# Function decide the return type by params

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I have two interfaces:

```
interface ChildConfig {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
interface Config {
  [name: string]: ChildConfig;
}
```

I want to have a function that has an optional param. When the param exists, I want the function to return `ChildConfig`, if not I want to return `Config`.

```
function getConfig(name?: string): ??? {
  if (name) return config[name];
  return config;
};
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you read the docs? The functions page has a section on this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Comment: You can either return `any` type or set `ChildConfig | Config` as a return type.

Comment: The return type `any` is a false best friend, because you lose all the consistency of typescript.

Comment: Also the union type means you have to then use assertions or type guards to figure out which you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) you can use *function overloads* to actually make this type-safe:

```
function getConfig(): Config
function getConfig(name: string): ChildConfig
function getConfig(name?: string): Config | ChildConfig {
  if (name) {
    return config[name];
  }
  return config;
};
```

Now the return type will be different depending on how you call it, and you won't need to use `as` assertions or type guards to figure out what got returned as you do when only using a union type like `Config | ChildConfig`.

Comment: You can set `ChildConfig | Config` as return type of implementation

Comment: @AlekseyL. you could, but it doesn't matter; *"the `function pickCard(x): any` piece is not part of the overload list, so it only has two overloads: one that takes an object and one that takes a number"*. It's just another thing to keep in sync as the function changes, so it's easier to set it to `any`.

Comment: I know, but it does matter for implementation itself (so you don't `return 1` for example or any random type)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function getConfig(name?: string): ChildConfig|Config {
  if (name) return config[name];
  return config;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate from other answers, giving another possible way, you can set the return type to `Config|ChildConfig`.

```
interface ChildConfig {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
interface Config {
  [name: string]: ChildConfig;
}

const config = {} as any;

function getConfig(name?: string): Config|ChildConfig {
  if (name) return config[name];
  return config;
};
```

The usage will require you to explicitely decide whether the return type is a `Config` or a `ChildConfig`, like this:

```
const childConfig = getConfig('myTest') as ChildConfig;
```

In this way `childConfig` will be of type `ChildConfig`.

Otherwise, you can combine such mechanism with **type guards** (read more [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html))

```
function isChildConfig(arg: any): arg is ChildConfig {
    return arg && arg.x && arg.y;
}
```

Then use the type guard on the result to procede only if it's a child config:

```
const _config = getConfig('test');
if (isChildConfig(_config)) {
    _config. // <-- intellisense here
}
```

This will ensure that _config has `x` and `y` properties:

[image]

[TS Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAtgBsAmqD2IMwA5sgN4BQyyAHgFzIgCuAtgEbQDc1yAnoxYdulAL6VQkWIhQEipCrwDaIOKwiMAzmCigSAXUYZseQsRI9xlBIW3Ib8sgF4Ko5HE3uQfHpRjMQBDBgQmQSCDA5cwAKVXUAfi0dPQBKIzNSAB9jXCiFKhpgGGRYtQgU5CgI5igQewySFTL9HhoqsBq6h3NLX39A4NDgTRzTR2i4KBJGOG809ynkYbRMXIbFGjbq2oWyADI93YA6WmQD458xSmtbMGQAfW6FF3DIhuiAckhtD5SeIpKw1GeRI0UeDRSFQKm3BjiOYiAA)